# Accessing module in lib directory (Ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to access a function in a module that is located in the lib directory of my app. (lib/search.rb)

I am actually trying to get zip code searching working from:
http://joshhuckabee.com/simple-zip-code-perimeter-search-rails

**lib/search.rb**

```
module Search
  def zip_code_perimeter_search(zip, radius)
   #code
  end
end
```

I am trying to call the zip_code_perimeter_search function from the rails console or from my controller, both times I get undefined method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your console/controller:

```
include Search
zip_code_perimeter_search(zip, radius)
```

In case it doesn't auto-load in Rails 3, in your config/application.rb file, you can do this:

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Comment: Thanks, I also had to do a require for lib/search. I guess rails 3 doesn't autoload lib.

Comment: I've edited the answer. If you configure the load directories setting in your application.rb file, you won't need to 'require' the file.

Comment: I'm attempting the same thing, but I keep getting this error when I try to access my module even after modifying the config as you've outlined above. Its crashing on this line: `include Scrape` and throwing this error `uninitialized constant Admin::AdoptionsController::Scrape`

Answer (score 2):

For calling a module method directly include it in a class and then call it on class instance.

```
Class call_module_method
    include Search
end
```

Now

```
call_module_method.new.zip_code_perimeter_search(zip, radius)
```

will evaluate the code inside method `zip_code_perimeter_search(zip, radius)`