# Module just doesn't get loaded in the Model [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

Before you marked this questions as duplicated, I've checked this other very related questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525350/uninitialized-constant-error-when-including-a-module), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392708/rails-cant-access-a-module-in-my-lib-directory), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221411/accessing-module-in-lib-directory-ruby-on-rails) and [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007685/rails-4-uninitialized-constant-for-module), and basically, all of them is the same way to load the `lib` modules, but `User` still keeps throwing an error.

**models/user.rb**

```
# This line throws an error:
# cannot load such file -- my-project-root/lib/model_with_properties.rb
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/model_with_properties.rb"

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    # This line throws an error:
    # uninitialized constant User::ModelWithProperties
    include ModelWithProperties
    ...

end
```

**lib/model_with_properties.rb**

```
module ModelWithProperties

  # Some functions

end
```

**config/application.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
require 'yaml'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Project
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

    # Load the lib folder, a thousand times
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
    config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
  end
end
```

What am I missing?

**Another useful information:**

```
julian$ rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'
    Running via Spring preloader in process 38445
    /my-project-root/lib
    /my-project-root/lib/
    /my-project-root/lib/assets/
    /my-project-root/lib/tasks/
    /my-project-root/app/assets
    /my-project-root/app/controllers
    /my-project-root/app/helpers
    /my-project-root/app/jobs
    /my-project-root/app/mailers
    /my-project-root/app/models
    /my-project-root/app/controllers/concerns
    /my-project-root/app/models/concerns
    /my-project-root/test/mailers/previews

julian$ rails -v
    Rails 4.2.3
```

**Answer**

Big thanks to @jvillian, I was using RubyMine and I assumed the file extensions were hidden, and all that matter was the Ruby Icon on the IDE. Actually the `.rb` extension was missing.

[image]

Comment: Ugh! I've been wrestling with AutoLoading Constants in the last few days. Not nice. If you're in console, what do you get when you `require 'model_with_properties'`?

Comment: Either add `lib` into your autoload paths or `require` the file manually, not both.

Comment: Sometimes, Spring needs to be reloaded. Try running `spring stop` and restart your application.

Comment: @jvillian I get this `> require 'model_with_properties'
=> cannot load such file -- model_with_properties`

Comment: @Stefan I've commented the `require` line in the model, so adding the lib should work. It doesn't :(

Comment: @Stefan just stopped spring, and restarted, no luck.

Comment: Yes, @Stefan. `spring stop` is a good place to start.

Comment: Double check your constants and file names for typos.

Comment: What about `Dir["#{Rails.root.join('lib','**','*.rb')}"]` in console?

Comment: @jvillian empty: `Dir["#{Rails.root.join('lib','**','*.rb')}"]
=> []`

Comment: `Dir["lib/**/*.rb"]`?

Comment: @jvillian `Dir["lib/**/*.rb"]
=> []` and `Rails.root.join('lib','**','*.rb')
=> #<Pathname:/my-project-root/lib/**/*.rb>`

Comment: Are you sure the file is in the lib directory and has the .rb extension? Sorry for such a dumb question, but `Dir["lib/**/*.rb"] => []` is curious.

Comment: @jvillian that was it. I feel so dumb I didn't notice. IDE was showing the ruby icon :/ Updated the question. If you want post the answer and I'll choose it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In console, do `Dir["lib/**/*.rb"]` to make sure the file is actually there. Once you fix that, try removing the `require` statement in `user.rb` (as @Stefan suggests). Not altogether necessary, but `require` statements can sometimes mess with AutoLoading.